# Radio buttons within Accordion

Tags: accordion

Newbie here.

At item creation, the user needs to select one of the available descriptions.

They are grouped by Category. Categories are self exclusive and users are trained so choosing category is not an issue.

[image]

Is there better way of doing this?

The Description list in each category is fluid, so printing all available descriptions would not work.

Answer (score 1):

Do these need to be nested in accordions at all? Is the accordion being used to make the user choose a category or to save space?

You could look at:

1. You could also look at making it sequential (sequencing), like hop app onboarding works?

   - See some examples here: https://uimovement.com/tag/onboarding/
2. OR look at just breaking them out of the accordion and having them one under the other, this will make for a quicker experience when filling them in while making the user choose a category.

   Consider the UI here, for example: you could place them in cards so it makes the user choose one (a little like how price plan pages look for subscriptions on software look etc).

   See some examples here:

   - https://www.weebly.com/uk/pricing
   - https://www.invisionapp.com/plans
   - https://mailchimp.com/pricing/
   - https://www.typeform.com/pricing/

   In my experience users are generally OK filling out forms if they are getting something from it, in this case creating something, I’m assuming they are creating or configuring something? I don’t know the specifics based on the question.
3. As *BrunoH* says, use a drop down. But personally I would only use a drop down here if the copy is fairly short, not the multi line length of copy you have in your visuals, I personally think that is alot for a drop down, especially on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You could have two screens. The first with a list of the categories to choose from. If the user selects one, the next screen pops up showing the radiobuttons with the description lists.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this as a list of dropdowns. Advantage over the accordion: the user sees what she selected.
[image]